# Share data between Activities/Presenters in GWT

Tags: gwt, android-activity

II want to share data between Activities (which are my presenters) without passing the data with the Place. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data really isn't all that large I'd try and encode it in the Place: then your users can bookmark/distribute URLs that lead right into the guts of the application (link to a specific product, search filter, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Quite some ways. A simple way is -

you could create a public static field in some class and use that in all of your presenters . (This method obviously has strings attached and must be used carefully)

Jai